# Flutter: Add trailing zero if the decimal value is one when converted from double to string

Tags: flutter

What is the best way to add zero to a string when converted from double in some case in Flutter?

Suppose that I have the following **string**:

> 12.5 -->12.50
>
> 12.55 ----> 12.55
>
> 12 ----> 12.00

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a double to start with, as I interpret you have before conversion to String. Then, instead of regular `toString()`, do this:

```
final myString = myDouble.toStringAsFixed(2)
```

See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html